# Matching decimals in strings using matcher()

Tags: java, string, decimal, matcher

I have a question regarding the matcher. Currently I am trying to read a string and store all the digits into an array. My question is, how do you try to match both integers and decimals?

I have an array of doubles called:

> double[] thisArray = new double[20];

Into this array, i am trying to store all the numbers I extract from the string.

> Matcher temp =
>   Pattern.compile("(\d+)").matcher(x);

That is my function for the matcher. But this only matches integers. I want to match both integers and decimals like (5.2). But how do I do this? I want to be able to enter in both integers and decimals into my string.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will handle both integer and decimals:-

```
private Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");

@Test
public void testInteger() {
    Matcher m =p.matcher("10");

    assertTrue(m.find());
    assertEquals("10", m.group());
}

@Test
public void testDecimal() {
    Matcher m =p.matcher("10.99");

    assertTrue(m.find());
    assertEquals("10.99", m.group());
}
```

Comment: I see what you had there, you had both a digit by itself and also the \\.\\d+ was optional. Thank you it works!

Comment: Does this also take care of negative decimal numbers?

Answer (score 0):

The phrase `\d+` will match a string of numbers. So what about adding a dot between two of them?  `(\d+)|(\d+|\.\d+)`