# JavaFX : TextField max and min value by listener

Tags: javafx, jtextfield

I need to limit interval of the text property of a text field

```
int maxLength = 64;
    int minLength = 0;
    txtSeuil.textProperty().addListener((v, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (!newValue.matches("\\d*")) {
            txtSeuil.setText(newValue.replaceAll("[^\\d*{1,2}]", ""));
            if (txtSeuil.getText().length() > maxLength || txtSeuil.getText().length() < minLength) {
                String s = txtSeuil.getText().substring(0, maxLength);
                txtSeuil.setText(s);
            }
        }

    });
```

the field does accept only numbers but any number, not just the interval values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, you're trying to implement a number field that only allows values within the interval [0, 64]. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16554408/3429133), [`TextFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html) is the recommended way to accomplish such a functionality. Have a look at this [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which should solve your problem:

```
public class RestrictedNumberFieldDemo extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField numField = new TextField();
        numField.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<Integer>(change -> {
            // Deletion should always be possible.
            if (change.isDeleted()) {
                return change;
            }

            // How would the text look like after the change?
            String txt = change.getControlNewText();

            // There shouldn't be leading zeros.
            if (txt.matches("0\\d+")) {
                return null;
            }

            // Try parsing and check if the result is in [0, 64].
            try {
                int n = Integer.parseInt(txt);
                return 0 <= n && n <= 64 ? change : null;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(numField));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

To solve your problem you can implement custom `Filter` for [TextFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html). It will allow to enter numbers only and restrict length of string. Here is snippet which show how it can works:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main5 extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<Integer>(change -> {
            if (!change.getText().isEmpty()) {
                return change.getText().matches("\\d+") && change.getControlNewText().length() <= 5 ? change : null;
            }

            return change;
        }));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(textField));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, it works for the length but I made a mistake on the code, the minValue and maxValue that I want are not for the length value but vor the text value, so how can I fix that ?

Comment: @devhicham what do you mean by "text value"? Only numbers from 0 – 64?

Comment: @beatngu13 yes please, I want that the field accept only this interval numbers from 0 to 64

Comment: @devhicham then have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41514479/3429133).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is:

The length check is not done, if the regex matches. But the text can be a sequence of digits **and** be to long.

You need to do those checks independent of each other.

Also you're setting a new value in some cases which triggers the same checks again. Of course they will result in the `String` being evaluates as a valid input, but you could prevent checking again by introducing a field in the `ChangeListener` that stores, whether the listener is currently being executed:

```
txtSeuil.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {

    private boolean validating = false;

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
        if (!validating) {
            validating = true;
            String newText = newValue;
            boolean modify = false;
            if (!newValue.matches("\\d*")) {
                newText = newValue.replaceAll("[^\\d*{1,2}]", "");
                modify = true;
            }
            if (newText.length() > maxLength || newText.length() < minLength) {
                newText = newText.substring(0, maxLength);
                modify = true;
            }
            if (modify) {
                txtSeuil.setText(newText);
            }
            validating = false;
        }
    }
});
```