# Time or duration control?

Tags: time, controls, javafx-2, duration

In my application the users needs to be able to enter a duration, consisting of minutes and seconds.

I am thinking of something like the control used in Windows to change the time, though I only need minutes and seconds and also the arrows would be nice, but are not necessary.

- Is there already a control for this in JavaFX 2?
- If not, how can I create such a control?

A screenshot of the mentioned Windows control:

[image]

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no such control in standard JavaFX 2.

Although you can try to look at `Spinner` control from JFXtras project: http://jfxtras.org/

And intergrate it with TextEdit filtering approach described here: [What is the recommended way to make a numeric TextField in JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555564/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-make-a-numeric-textfield-in-javafx)

Answer (score 1):

Nice implementation of spinner, though you need to adjust it to handle time inputs.
[JavaFX NumberTextField and Spinner Control](http://java.dzone.com/articles/javafx-numbertextfield-and).