# Restrict text input inside combobox

Tags: combobox, javafx

I need to restrict text input inside combobox with positive numbers. I've searched stackoverflow for this and found similar question:  [Recommended way to restrict input in JavaFX textfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615890/recommended-way-to-restrict-input-in-javafx-textfield)

The only difference is that the mentioned question addresses bare textfield. The answer approved by the javafx designers is to extend the `TextField` class and override couple of methods: `replaceText` and `replaceSelection`. This hack does not work with combobox: `TextField` instance if stored inside and is avaiable as *read-only* property named `editor`.

So what is the recommended way to restrict text input inside javafx combobox?

Answer (score 1):

Since this question question never got a proper answer I'm adding a solution I've implemented that restricts the user to input that matches a regular expression and is shorter than a particular length (this is optional). This is done by adding a `ChangeListener` to the editor `TextField`. Any input that doesn't match will not get written into the editor `TextField`.

This example restricts the user to a maximum of two numeric characters.

```
ComboBox<Integer> integerComboBox = new ComboBox<Integer>();
integerComboBox.setEditable(true);
integerComboBox.getEditor().textProperty()
            .addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {

                // The max length of the input
                int maxLength = 2;

                // The regular expression controlling the input, in this case we only allow number 0 to 9.
                String restriction = "[0-9]";

                private boolean ignore;

                @Override
                public void changed(
                        ObservableValue<? extends String> observableValue,
                        String oldValue, String newValue) {
                    if (ignore || newValue == null) {
                        return;
                    }

                    if (newValue.length() > maxLength) {
                        ignore = true;
                        integerComboBox.getEditor().setText(
                                newValue.substring(0, maxLength));
                        ignore = false;
                    }

                    if (!newValue.matches(restriction + "*")) {
                        ignore = true;
                        integerComboBox.getEditor().setText(oldValue);
                        ignore = false;
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: As of Java8u40, you can also use a TextFormatter instead of a change listener.

Answer (score 0):

You might register a check method on the editor property to check if any input is accpetable.

Here I allow editing, but draw a red frame if values are not in the items list.

```
ObservableList<String> myChoices = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

void testComboBoxCheck(VBox box) {
    myChoices.add("A");
    myChoices.add("B");
    myChoices.add("C");

    ComboBox<String> first = new ComboBox<String>();
    first.setItems(myChoices);
    first.setEditable(true);
    first.editorProperty().getValue().textProperty().addListener((v, o, n) -> {
        if (myChoices.contains(n.toUpperCase())) {
            first.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.rgb(30,30,30), new CornerRadii(0), new Insets(0))));
        } else {
            first.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.RED, new CornerRadii(0), new Insets(0))));
        }
    });

    box.getChildren().addAll(first);
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Many commentators in similar questions related to the TextField class discourage this way. I does not know why.

Answer (score 0):

How about decouplign the Text editor from the ComboBox and link their values?

```
    HBox combo = new HBox();

    TextField editor = new TextField();

    ComboBox<String> first = new ComboBox<String>();
    first.setItems(myChoices);
    first.setButtonCell(new ComboBoxListCell<String>(){
        @Override public void updateItem(String s, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(s, empty);
            setText(null);
        }
    });

    editor.textProperty().bindBidirectional(first.valueProperty());

    combo.getChildren().addAll(editor, first);
    box.getChildren().addAll(combo);
```

Now you have full conroll over the TextField allowing to override any methods etc.