# Java 8 U40 TextFormatter (JavaFX) to restrict user input only for decimal number

Tags: javafx, java-8, javafx-8

I am looking for an example to restrict user input to only digits and decimal points using the new class `TextFormatter` of Java8 u40. 
http://download.java.net/jdk9/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.Change.html

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Please see this example:

```
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat( "#.0" );

TextField field = new TextField();
field.setTextFormatter( new TextFormatter<>(c ->
{
    if ( c.getControlNewText().isEmpty() )
    {
        return c;
    }

    ParsePosition parsePosition = new ParsePosition( 0 );
    Object object = format.parse( c.getControlNewText(), parsePosition );

    if ( object == null || parsePosition.getIndex() < c.getControlNewText().length() )
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        return c;
    }
}));
```

- Here I used the [TextFormatter(UnaryOperator filter)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html#TextFormatter-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-) constructor which takes a filter only as a parameter.
- To understand the if-statement refer to [DecimalFormat parse(String text, ParsePosition pos)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-java.text.ParsePosition-).

Comment: Any recommendation on books to read? I am still new to Java, and I need a little more explanation. I looked at "Java The Complete Reference Ninth Edition" but I found nothing related to this. I even couldn't find the usages of replaceText and replaceSelection in there. I am not sure if I am looking in the wrong place or not,  where can I find some reading about the replaceText/Selection?

Comment: There are separate books on JavaFX only. So first read a book on Java first then on JavaFX. If you know other programming languages like C/C++ or C#, you can easily learn Java as well. By the way, I didn't use replaceText/Selection in the answer but you are asking about it. It is bit out of context. Despite this see [this searches](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavafx%5D+or+%5Bjavafx-2%5D+or+%5Bjavafx-8%5D+replacetext). And is this my post answers your question?

Comment: Yes, It did. Thanks again for your follow up on my comments.

Comment: The formatters that come with java aren't very good for this sort of thing. For instance, I can't start typing with a leading negative sign but can go back and add it later. Because of this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/40472822/2331302 is a better answer

Comment: What would be the pattern to accept negative decimal numbers as well?