# Java textbox accepting specif number

Tags: user-interface, javafx

I am planning to make a maths game there will be one question like 1+ 1 as an image in Javafx. The textbox provided will give the user to input the number how do for example for 1+1 just allow the user to put in 2 and for everything else it will not accept then number in the text box.  and display a message try again or something similar.

Basicly how do I restrict the text box for a specific number

Comment: Please show your effort. What you have tried?

Comment: thats the idea i have in my mind so have not really done it

Comment: So why not to start coding that logic, and if you will have difficulties update your question accordingly.

Comment: is it possible to contact you directly i can explain it fully to you if you don't mind?

Comment: Sorry I am going away from my laptop. Besides this, I totally understood your problem. Simply add key event filter listener to textfield's text property and accept only the "2". And another way is to use textfield's filtering feature, you need a modified version of [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31043122)