# JavaFX 8 | TextField allows only numbers and decimals

Tags: java, javafx

```
//Only Allow Numeric Data Types in Hard Drive TextField
        txtPurchaseCost.setOnKeyTyped(e -> {
            char input = e.getCharacter().charAt(0);
            if (Character.isDigit(input) != true) {
                e.consume();
            }
        });
```

Currently have this code that allows me to only allow numeric values into my TextField. Was wondering how I can make it so I can also allow decimals so the number is in currency format (201.21, 122.00, 12,122.12)

Also thousands separators and only allowing two decimal places would be great but not really important

Comment: I would recommend [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40472668/numeric-textfield-for-integers-in-javafx-8-with-textformatter-and-or-unaryoperat/40472822) using text formatter.

Comment: Why not using a Spinner with the opportune ValueFactory? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Spinner.html