# Escape from a Number TextField in a JavaFX dialog

Tags: javafx

I've a custom dialog with several UI elements. Some TextFields are for [numeric input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31043122). This dialog does not close when the escape key is hit and the focus is on any of the numeric text fields. The dialog closes fine when focus is on other TextFields which do not have this custom TextFormatter.

Here's the simplified code:

```
package application;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.ParsePosition;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            TextField name = new TextField();
            HBox hb1 = new HBox();
            hb1.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Name: "), name);

            TextField id = new TextField();
            id.setTextFormatter(getNumberFormatter()); // numbers only
            HBox hb2 = new HBox();
            hb2.getChildren().addAll(new Label("ID: "), id);

            VBox vbox = new VBox();
            vbox.getChildren().addAll(hb1, hb2);

            Dialog<ButtonType> dialog = new Dialog<>();
            dialog.setTitle("Number Escape");
            dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(ButtonType.OK, ButtonType.CANCEL);
            dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(vbox);

            Platform.runLater(() -> name.requestFocus());

            if (dialog.showAndWait().get() == ButtonType.OK) {
                System.out.println("OK: " + name.getText() + id.getText());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Cancel");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    TextFormatter<Number> getNumberFormatter() {
        // from https://stackoverflow.com/a/31043122
        DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#");
        TextFormatter<Number> tf = new TextFormatter<>(c -> {
            if (c.getControlNewText().isEmpty()) {
                return c;
            }
            ParsePosition parsePosition = new ParsePosition(0);
            Object object = format.parse(c.getControlNewText(), parsePosition);
            if (object == null || parsePosition.getIndex() < c.getControlNewText().length()) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return c;
            }
        });

        return tf;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

How do I close the dialog when escape key is hit while focus is on `id`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## The Problem

Before offering a solution I think it's important, or at least interesting, to understand *why* having a `TextFormatter` seems to change the behavior of the `Dialog`. If this doesn't matter to you, feel free to jump to the end of the answer.

#### Cancel Buttons

According to [the documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Button.html) of `Button`, a cancel button is:

> the button that receives a keyboard VK_ESC press, if no other node in the scene consumes it.

The end of that sentence is the important part. The way cancel buttons, as well as default buttons, are implemented is by registering [an accelerator](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Scene.html#getAccelerators()) with the `Scene` that the `Button` belongs to. These accelerators are only invoked if the appropriate `KeyEvent` *bubbles* up to the `Scene`. If the event is consumed before it reaches the `Scene`, the accelerator is not invoked.

***Note:** To understand more about event processing in JavaFX, especially terms such as "bubbles" and "consumed", I suggest reading [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/events.htm).*

#### Dialogs

A `Dialog` has certain rules regarding how and when it can be closed. These rules are [documented here](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html), in the *Dialog Closing Rules* section. Suffice to say, basically everything depends on which `ButtonType`s have been added to the `DialogPane`. In your example you use one of the predefined types: `ButtonType.CANCEL`. If you look at [the documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ButtonType.html#CANCEL) of that field, you'll see:

> A pre-defined `ButtonType` that displays "Cancel" and has a `ButtonBar.ButtonData` of `ButtonBar.ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE`.

And if you look at [the documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ButtonBar.ButtonData.html#CANCEL_CLOSE) of `ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE`, you'll see:

> A tag for the "cancel" or "close" button.
>
> **Is cancel button:** True

What this means, at least for the default implementation, is that the `Button` created for said `ButtonType.CANCEL` will be a cancel button. In other words, the `Button` will have its `cancelButton` property set to `true`. This is what allows one to close a `Dialog` by pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

***Note:** It's the [`DialogPane#createButton(ButtonType)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/DialogPane.html#createButton(javafx.scene.control.ButtonType)) method that's responsible for creating the appropriate button (and can be overridden for customization). While the return type of that method is `Node` it is typical, as documented, to return an instance of `Button`.*

#### The TextFormatter

Every control in (core) JavaFX has three components: the control class, the skin class, and the behavior class. The latter class is responsible for handling user input, such as mouse and key events. In this case, we care about `TextInputControlBehavior` and `TextFieldBehavior`; the former is the superclass of the latter.

***Note:** Unlike the skin classes, which became public API in JavaFX 9, the behavior classes are still private API as of JavaFX 12.0.2. Much of what's described below are implementation details.*

The `TextInputControlBehavior` class registers an `EventHandler` that reacts to the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key being pressed, invoking the `cancelEdit(KeyEvent)` method of the same class. All the base implementation of this method does is forward the `KeyEvent` to the `TextInputControl`'s parent, if it has one—resulting in two event dispatching cycles for some unknown (to me) reason. However, the `TextFieldBehavior` class overrides this method:

> ```
> @Override
> protected void cancelEdit(KeyEvent event) {
>     TextField textField = getNode();
>     if (textField.getTextFormatter() != null) {
>         textField.cancelEdit();
>         event.consume();
>     } else {
>         super.cancelEdit(event);
>     }
> }
> ```

As you can see, the presence of a `TextFormatter` causes the `KeyEvent` to be unconditionally consumed. This stops the event from reaching the `Scene`, the cancel button is not fired, and thus the `Dialog` does not close when the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key is pressed while the `TextField` has the focus. When there is no `TextFormatter` the super implementation is invoked which, as stated before, simply forwards the event to the parent.

The reason for this behavior is hinted at by the call to `TextInputControl#cancelEdit()`. That method has a "sister method" in the form of `TextInputControl#commitValue()`. If you look at the documentation of those two methods, you'll see:

> If the field is currently being edited, this call will set text to the last commited value.

And:

> Commit the current text and convert it to a value.

Respectively. That doesn't explain much, unfortunately, but if you look at the implementation their purpose becomes clear. A `TextFormatter` has a `value` property which is *not* updated in real time while typing into the `TextField`. Instead, the value is only updated when it's committed (e.g. by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>). The reverse is also true; the current text can be reverted to the current value by cancelling the edit (e.g. by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>).

***Note:** The conversion between `String` and an object of arbitrary type is handled by the `StringConverter` associated with the `TextFormatter`.*

When there's a `TextFormatter`, the act of cancelling the edit is deemed an event-consuming scenario. This makes sense, I suppose. However, even when there's nothing to cancel the event is still consumed—this doesn't make as much sense to me.

---

## A Solution

One way to fix this is to dig into the internals, using reflection, as is shown in [kleopatra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57396885/6395627). Another option is to add an event filter to the `TextField` or some ancestor of the `TextField` that closes the `Dialog` when the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key is pressed.

```
textField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> {
    if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
        event.consume();
        dialog.close();
    }
});
```

If you'd like to include the cancel-edit behavior (cancel without closing) then you should only close the `Dialog` if there's no edit to cancel. Take a look at kleopatra's answer to see how one might determine whether or not a cancel is needed. If there is something to cancel simply don't consume the event and don't close the `Dialog`. If there isn't anything to cancel then just do the same as the code above (i.e. consume and close).

Is using an event filter the "recommended way"? It's certainly a valid way. JavaFX is [event-driven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) like most, if not all, mainstream UI toolkits. For JavaFX specifically that means reacting to `Event`s or observing `Observable[Value]`s for invalidations/changes. A framework built "on top of" JavaFX may add its own mechanisms. Since the problem is an event being consumed when we don't want it to be, it is valid to add your own handlers to implement the desired behavior.

Comment: this works on `id`. And also on parent/ancestors which surprised me. But why doesn't the default handler work when a text formatter is added? Also wondering if this is the recommended way in JavaFX...

Comment: @rubpa Edited my answer to address your comment.

Comment: wow! Thanks for all the details added. It indeed clarified several things.

Comment: really good answer, wasn't aware of that particular tweak in the bowels :) An alternative approach - for somebody allowed/courage enough to wade into muddy waters - is to replace the keybinding in the field's inputMap that's installed by the behaviour. Dirtyness comes two-fold: a) need to reflectively access the private behaviour field in the skin b) change the inputMap which is an internal class (unfortunately, didn't make it into public scope when skins were moved out into the open)

Comment: @kleopatra Thanks :) You're right, of course—reflection is another option. It'd be nice if the behavior classes finally become public (and documented well, unlike those CSS-related classes that became public in FX 9... though maybe I just don't understand CSS well enough). Do you have any idea why they made it so the presence of a `TextFormatter` stops the event from propagating?

Comment: technically, it was introduced when fixing [Popup not closed on esc when textfield in popup is focused](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8090230) - the code changed from auto-consuming always to only with textformatter. As to the why: the idea might be that reverting back to the last committed value is a consuming interaction. Which would be the correct thingy if `textfield.text != textformatter.value` - without that it's unexpected ..

Comment: @kleopatra Ah, I think I've just never realized the full use of `TextFormatter`. I'm going to update my answer in a few hours to address the whole cancel edit thing (right now my answer simply bypasses that entirely).

Answer (score 4):

The question already has an [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50971659/203657), nothing to add. Just wanted to demonstrate how to tweak the behavior's InputMap to inject/replace our own mappings (as a follow-up to my comment). Beware: it's dirty in reflectively accessing a skin's behavior (private final field) and using internal api (Behavior/InputMap didn't make it into public, yet).

As Slaw pointed out, it's the behavior that prevents the ESCAPE from bubbling up to the cancel button if the TextField has a TextFormatter installed. IMO, it's not misbehaving in that case, just overshooting: the cancel/default buttons should be triggered on ESCAPE/ENTER if and only if no other had used it to change the state of the any input nodes (my somewhat free interpretation of *consumed* - had done some research on general UX guidelines that I can't find right now, embarassingly ...)

Applied to a form containing both a textField with textFormatter and a cancel button (aka: isCancelButton is true)

- if the textField has uncommitted text, a cancel should revert the edit to the most recent committed value and consume the event
- if the textField is committed it should let it bubble up to trigger the cancel button

The implementation of cancelEdit in behavior doesn't distinguish between those two states, but always consumes it. The example below implements the expected (by me, at least) behavior. It has

- a helper method to decide whether or not is dirty (aka: the textField has an uncommitted edit)
- a event handling method that checks for dirtyness, calls cancel and consumes the event only it had been dirty
- a configuration method that tweaks the textFields inputMap such that the mapping is replaced by our own.

Note that this is a PoC: doesn't belong into helpers but into a custom skin (at the very least, ideally should be done by the behavior). And it is missing similar support for the  ENTER .. which is slightly more involved because it has to take actionHandlers into account (which behavior tries to but [fails to achieve](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8207774))

To test the example:

- compile (note: you need to reflectively access a private field, use whatever you have at hand - we all do, don't we) and run
- type something into the field
- press escape: the field's text is reverted to its initial value
- press escape again: the cancel button is triggered

The example code:

```
public class TextFieldCancelSO extends Application {

    /**
     * Returns a boolean to indicate whether the given field has uncommitted
     * changes.
     * 
     * @param <T> the type of the formatter's value
     * @param field the field to analyse
     * @return true if the field has a textFormatter with converter and
     *    uncommitted changes, false otherwise
     */
    public static <T> boolean isDirty(TextField field) {
        TextFormatter<T> textFormatter = (TextFormatter<T>) field.getTextFormatter();
        if (textFormatter == null || textFormatter.getValueConverter() == null) return false;
        String fieldText = field.getText();
        StringConverter<T> valueConverter = textFormatter.getValueConverter();
        String formatterText = valueConverter.toString(textFormatter.getValue());
        // todo: handle empty string vs. null value
        return !Objects.equals(fieldText, formatterText);
    }

    /**
     * Install a custom keyMapping for ESCAPE in the inputMap of the given field. 
     * @param field the textField to configure
     */
    protected void installCancel(TextField field) {
        // Dirty: reflectively access the behavior
        // needs --add-exports at compile- and runtime! 
        // note: FXUtils is a custom helper class not contained in core fx, use your own 
        // helper or write the field access code as needed.
        TextFieldBehavior behavior = (TextFieldBehavior) FXUtils.invokeGetFieldValue(
                TextFieldSkin.class, field.getSkin(), "behavior");
        // Dirty: internal api/classes
        InputMap inputMap = behavior.getInputMap();
        KeyBinding binding = new KeyBinding(KeyCode.ESCAPE);
        // custom mapping that delegates to helper method
        KeyMapping keyMapping = new KeyMapping(binding, e ->  {
            cancelEdit(field, e);
        });
        // by default, mappings consume the event - configure not to
        keyMapping.setAutoConsume(false);
        // remove old
        inputMap.getMappings().remove(keyMapping);
        // add new
        inputMap.getMappings().add(keyMapping);
    }

    /**
     * Custom EventHandler that's mapped to ESCAPE.
     * 
     * @param field the field to handle a cancel for
     * @param ev the received keyEvent 
     */
    protected void cancelEdit(TextField field, KeyEvent ev) {
        boolean dirty = isDirty(field);
        field.cancelEdit();
        if (dirty) {
           ev.consume();
        }
    }

    private Parent createContent() {
        TextFormatter<String> fieldFormatter = new TextFormatter<>(
                TextFormatter.IDENTITY_STRING_CONVERTER, "textField ...");
        TextField field = new TextField();
        field.setTextFormatter(fieldFormatter);
        // listen to skin: behavior is available only after it's set
        field.skinProperty().addListener((src, ov, nv) -> {
            installCancel(field);
        });
        // just to see the state of the formatter
        Label fieldValue = new Label();
        fieldValue.textProperty().bind(fieldFormatter.valueProperty());

        // add cancel button
        Button cancel = new Button("I'm the cancel");
        cancel.setCancelButton(true);
        cancel.setOnAction(e -> LOG.info("triggered: " + cancel.getText()));

        HBox fields = new HBox(100, field, fieldValue);
        BorderPane content = new BorderPane(fields);
        content.setBottom(cancel);
        return content;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(createContent()));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger
            .getLogger(TextFieldCancelSO.class.getName());

}
```