# how to control Javafx Textfield input so it wont accept space

Tags: javafx, fxml

I made a textfield in JavaFX of username, I want to run a method that checks if there is a space or not! , is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Try using a [`TextFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html) and post a specific question if you can't get it to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the recommended way to make a numeric TextField in JavaFX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555564/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-make-a-numeric-textfield-in-javafx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[TextFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html)'s filter**

> This filter([UnaryOperator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/UnaryOperator.html?is-external=true)) allows a user to intercept and modify any change done to the text content. Here is an example which sets no change on space value.

```
TextField field = new TextField();

field.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<>(change -> {
    if (change.getText().equals(" ")) {
        change.setText("");
    }
    return change;
}));
```