# Common function to make JavaFX TextField accepts only numeric input

Tags: lambda, javafx-8, textfield, numeric

I found this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555564/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-make-a-numeric-textfield-in-javafx)  useful to make a JavaFX TextField accepts only numeric values. However I would like to simplify the solution so that it can be implemented on multiple TextFields.

Looking for something like :

```
ChangeListener<String> numericTextFieldListener = (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if(!newValue.matches("\\d*")) {
        //textField.setText(newValue.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "")); //how to set this new value to parent text field?
    }
};

textField1.textProperty().addListener(numericTextFieldListener);
textField2.textProperty().addListener(numericTextFieldListener);
textField3.textProperty().addListener(numericTextFieldListener);
textField4.textProperty().addListener(numericTextFieldListener);
// ... and so on
```

Any recommendation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1**

You can simply make new class that implements ChangeListener and pass TextField as an argument in the constructor.

```
class MyChangeListener implements ChangeListener<String> {

    TextField txt;

    public MyChangeListener(TextField txt) {
        this.txt = txt;
    }

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
        if (!newValue.matches("\\d*")) {
            txt.setText(newValue.replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""));
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can instantiate MyChangeListener and apply custom ChangeListener to your textFields like this.

```
textField1.textProperty().addListener(new MyChangeListener(textField1));
textField2.textProperty().addListener(new MyChangeListener(textField2));
textField3.textProperty().addListener(new MyChangeListener(textField3));
```

**Method 2**

You can make custom TextField like this.

```
class NumericalTextField extends TextField {

    public NumericalTextField() {
        super();
        addListener();
    }

    public NumericalTextField(String txt) {
        super(txt);
        addListener();
    }

    private void addListener() {
        this.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (!newValue.matches("\\d*")) {
                this.setText(newValue.replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and instantiate.

```
TextField txt1 = new NumericalTextField();
TextField txt2 = new NumericalTextField("Text");
```