# How to validate TextField if passing argument is string?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I wanted to validate the TextField of GUI, If user cannot enter string in size Text field that only take integers as an argument. Like catching Exceptions
[image]

Here is my code Its not catching the exception

```
public boolean validateTextField(){
    if(eventSizeField.getText().isEmpty() || eventNameField.getText().isEmpty()){
        alertboxCustom("Empty Field", "Please Enter Valid Name and size");
        return false;
    }else if(Integer.parseInt(eventSizeField.getText()) <= 0 ){
        alertboxCustom("EventSize", "Event Size must be greater than zero");
        return false;
    }try{
         Integer.parseInt(eventSizeField.getText());
    }catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        alertboxCustom("EventSize", e.getMessage());
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Every input from TextField is interpreted as String, you want to check if it's for example a number?

Comment: I know every input is a string, Name of the event take the string and Size of the event only take integers as an input to create an object. I want to display error alert box if someone try to enter string in that field.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to make it clear what you are asking. Do you want the text field to only be able to have numerical (integer? floating point? negative?) values? If so, explain that in the question in a way that is understandable.

Comment: @Reboot `if(Integer.parseInt(eventSizeField.getText()) <= 0 )` condition has to be after try catch otherwise try block makes no sense.

Comment: I already put my code in edited version

Comment: It worked, Thanks!

Comment: If you’re asking how to make a TextField accept only numbers, you probably want `eventSizeField.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<Number>(new NumberStringConverter(NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance())));`.

Comment: @VGR you need a filter there, as well as the converter.

Comment: you can use some thing like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/30796829/6296931

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use try catch for this:

```
    try {
            Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
            //Some operations
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            //Here for example prompt some window notifying user
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

Comment: Never use try-catch for logical processing. Exceptions are for exceptional conditions. You should write code to avoid converting the string to a number if it is not the correct format.

Comment: @Reboot What do you mean?

Comment: @Reboot It might "work", but as I pointed out this is a very poor solution.

Answer (score 0):

In java every text is string. 
get the string from text field

```
String stringValue=textField.getText();
```

To get integer value from string we can parse it using

```
  try{
    value=Integer.parseInt(stringValue)
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                //prompt some error or alert
    //reset text
      textField.setText("");
  }
```

Comment: Never use try-catch for logical processing. Exceptions are for exceptional conditions. You should write code to avoid converting the string to a number if it is not the correct format.

Comment: And also It will slow the speed