# How to force a double input in a TextField in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, input, textfield

How to make sure an **user inputs only double values** in a given TextField?

I found a [solution for integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555564/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-make-a-numeric-textfield-in-javafx) bu I can't manage to use it for doubles. What should I write instead of the `"\\d*"` and `"[^\\d]"` to make it work for doubles?

```
textField.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
        if (!newValue.matches("\\d*")) {
            textField.setText(newValue.replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't use a listener; other observers of the text property will see the invalid input before it is reverted. Use a `TextFormatter` instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The approach of using a listener and reverting to valid values if invalid values are input by the user will work, but it can create issues if you have other listeners on the text field's `textProperty`. Those listeners will observe the invalid values as well as the valid ones, so they have to know to filter out any invalid values.

A better approach is to use a [`TextFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html). The `TextFormatter` can do two things:

1. Define a "Filter", which can veto, or modify, any changes made to the `TextField`'s text
2. Define a "converter", which defines how to convert the text to and from values of any specific type (e.g. `Double`) in your case.

Defining the appropriate filter can be tricky: you want to allow any reasonable edits by the user. This means the text may be in an invalid state while the user is editing; e.g. you probably want to allow the text field to be completely empty, even though that does not represent a valid value. (Otherwise, it becomes annoying to the user if, for example, they want to change "1" to "2".) Similarly you probably want to allow things like "-" and ".", etc.

Here is an example. The filter should modify the change that is passed to it, if needed, and can return `null` to completely veto a change. This example simply checks if the text represents a valid editing state, and returns the change unmodified if it does, vetoing it otherwise. The formatter needs to deal with any text that is allowed by the filter and convert it to a double. Here anything that is incomplete is just represented as zero.

```
Pattern validEditingState = Pattern.compile("-?(([1-9][0-9]*)|0)?(\\.[0-9]*)?");

UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change> filter = c -> {
    String text = c.getControlNewText();
    if (validEditingState.matcher(text).matches()) {
        return c ;
    } else {
        return null ;
    }
};

StringConverter<Double> converter = new StringConverter<Double>() {

    @Override
    public Double fromString(String s) {
        if (s.isEmpty() || "-".equals(s) || ".".equals(s) || "-.".equals(s)) {
            return 0.0 ;
        } else {
            return Double.valueOf(s);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public String toString(Double d) {
        return d.toString();
    }
};

TextFormatter<Double> textFormatter = new TextFormatter<>(converter, 0.0, filter);
TextField textField = new TextField();
textField.setTextFormatter(textFormatter);
```

You can make the regular expression more complex if needed, e.g. to support grouping characters (`"1,000.0"`), localization (`"1.003,14159"` if that is appropriate for the locale), or scientific-notation-like representations (`"6.022E23"`, etc), and to enforce minimum or maximum values, etc. You can even do things such as modifying the change, so that if the user types a `-` anywhere in the text, it just flips the sign of the number. (Refer to the [`TextFormatter.Change` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.Change.html) for that kind of functionality.)

Note you can get and set the double value (as provided by the converter) directly from the formatter, which has an `ObjectProperty<Double> valueProperty()`. So you can do things like

```
// update text field:
double value = ... ;
textFormatter.setValue(value);

// listen for changes in double value represented in text field
// Listener will be invoked when the user commits an edit:

textFormatter.valueProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Double> obs, Double oldValue, Double newValue) -> {
    System.out.println("User entered value: "+newValue.doubleValue());
});
```

Here is a SSCCE. The second text field is just there so that you can see the effect of moving focus to a different control (it "commits" the value and invokes the listener on the text formatter, if the value has changed; a similar thing happens if the user presses enter).

```
import java.util.function.UnaryOperator;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

public class NumericTextField extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Pattern validEditingState = Pattern.compile("-?(([1-9][0-9]*)|0)?(\\.[0-9]*)?");

        UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change> filter = c -> {
            String text = c.getControlNewText();
            if (validEditingState.matcher(text).matches()) {
                return c ;
            } else {
                return null ;
            }
        };

        StringConverter<Double> converter = new StringConverter<Double>() {

            @Override
            public Double fromString(String s) {
                if (s.isEmpty() || "-".equals(s) || ".".equals(s) || "-.".equals(s)) {
                    return 0.0 ;
                } else {
                    return Double.valueOf(s);
                }
            }


            @Override
            public String toString(Double d) {
                return d.toString();
            }
        };

        TextFormatter<Double> textFormatter = new TextFormatter<>(converter, 0.0, filter);
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.setTextFormatter(textFormatter);

        textFormatter.valueProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Double> obs, Double oldValue, Double newValue) -> {
            System.out.println("User entered value: "+newValue.doubleValue());
        });

        VBox root = new VBox(5, textField, new TextField());
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 250, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: don't do any manual pattern matching, it'll break on most non-us/english Locales ..

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of Double.parseDouble [Double Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html). This will do the parsing for you, rather than writing your own double validation. You can then check for a number format exception or null pointer exception.

```
    try
    {
        Double.parseDouble(newValue);
        // Valid double
    }
    catch (NullPointerException | NumberFormatException ex)
    {
        // Not valid double
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm trying to **force** the user to input only double values. I would like to avoid managing invalid inputs.

Comment: There only way you can force a user to input a double is to detect an invalid input anyway. There's no difference between doing a if on a regex match or pulling the above code into a testDouble method which returns true or false.

Comment: "There only way you can force a user to input a double is to detect an invalid input anyway." Not true. You can override the various `insert` methods, for example, or use a `TextFormatter`.

Comment: It's also very bad practice to use exception handling for logical control. Exceptions should be for exceptional conditions, not something you expect to happen in the normal run of events.

Comment: using Double.parse is as bad as any manual pattern-matching: none is locale-aware. At the very least, you must use a NumberFormat ... inside a TextFormatter, as suggested by @James_D

Answer (score 0):

You can use the java regex on doubles and replace non-number characters with numbers. In  you have to specify the number of digits allowed in the integer part, for example 1,10.

```
textField.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
        if (!newValue.matches("[0-9]{<range>}(\\.[0-9]*)?")) {
            textField.setText(newValue.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", ""));
            StringBuilder aus = new StringBuilder(newValue);
            boolean firstPointFound = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < aus.length(); i++){
                if(aus.charAt(i) == '.') {
                    if(!firstPointFound)
                        firstPointFound = true;
                    else
                        aus.deleteCharAt(i);
                }
            }
            newValue = aus.toString();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in such a way if I try to input `99.99.` at the second `.` I get an error (and moreover the input is changed to `9999`). Any idea on how to fix this?