# ClassNotFoundException on new custom control - JavaFx

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, controls, classnotfoundexception

I am creating a simple project for my university, and at some point on my UI I wanted an Text Field in which the user input will be checked if it is a number or not. If yes, it will write the value to the Text Field. Otherwise it will leave it as it is. I must note that **I do not** want to use a spinner and also **I do not** want to create the custom control as a JAR and then import it. Now, I used the `NumericTextField` class that i took from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18959399/5900485), but when i try to use it I get from both intelliJ idea(console) and the scene builder this error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

I read several topics in stackoverflow that were talking for the specific issue, but none of these gave me a solution to my issue.

This is how I use the `NumericTextField` class from the fxml file:

```
<NumericTextField fx:id="simpleTxt" layoutX="53.0" layoutY="87.0" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="205.0" />
```

And the custom control i imported it in the fxml file like this:

```
<?import com.MyProjectName.NumericTextField?>
```

The code of the `NumericTextField` class:

```
package com.MyProjectName;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
public class NumericTextField extends TextField
{
    @Override
    public void replaceText(int start, int end, String text)
    {
        if (validate(text))
        {
            super.replaceText(start, end, text);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void replaceSelection(String text)
    {
        if (validate(text))
        {
            super.replaceSelection(text);
        }
    }
    private boolean validate(String text)
    {
        return text.matches("[0-9]");
    }
}
```

I load the form like this:
[image]

This is the error I get from the console:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1787)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8863)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:200)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:206)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3876)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1300(Scene.java:3604)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1874)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2613)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:189)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1784)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/miche/IdeaProjects/CS%20106%20-%20Final%20Project/out/production/CS%20106%20-%20Final%20Project/com/PatientManagementSystem/AddEditPatient.fxml
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2863)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processImport(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processProcessingInstruction(FXMLLoader.java:2676)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2542)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
    at com.PatientManagementSystem.MainFormController.OnInsertNewPatient(MainFormController.java:114)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.PatientManagementSystem$NumericTextField
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(FXMLLoader.java:2931)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:2920)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2861)
    ... 64 more
```

If there is someone that can spot what I am doing wrong, it will be great! Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Please include the code of your class, as well as the code used to load the FXML. Specifically - Is the class accessible? Does it have a public no-arg constructor?

Comment: @sillyfly I added the requested pieces of code. Tell me if I should upload something more.

Comment: In your code, the package of the class is `com.PatientManagementSystem`, yet in the FXML snippet, it is `com.MyProjectName`. If it is a typo that exists in the code as well (not just a mistake when you wrote it here) it could be your problem....

Comment: @sillyfly Yeah I saw that. It was just here in the article, not in the code.

Comment: The funny thing is that in other articles or videos( [like this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=os9Rn0PJYI0)), it seems to work like a charm. I don't understand why it does not work for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FXMLLoader` assumes you use the java naming conventions for packages/classes, i.e. you use package names starting with a lowercase letter and class names starting with an uppercase letter.

If `FXMLLoader` first encounters an identifier starting with an uppercase letter in the import, it assumes this is a class name which is why it's looking for the inner class named `NumericTextField` in a class named `PatientManagementSystem` in the `com` package. (Fully qualified name `com.PatientManagementSystem$NumericTextField`.)

You need to change your package name to lower case for `FXMLLoader` to load this class properly.

Comment: I love you man! I wasted 5 hours trying to find what the heck was happening. Accepted answer and upvote from me. Thank you very very much!

Comment: @blacklister sometimes a quick look at the javafx source code can be a life-saver: The `loadType` method basically contains the info even though I doubt it's documented anywhere.

Comment: A hint that the FXMLLoader is looking for an inner class is the `$` character in `com.PatientManagementSystem$NumericTextField`.