JavaFX Event Handling If Statement
I am designing a timer application. Right now, I would like the user to enter the number of minutes to set the timer. Here is my code so far:
VBox myLayout = new VBox();
        Arc timerFace = new Arc();
        TextField timeField = new TextField("Enter Timer Length (1-60min)");
        myLayout.getChildren().add(timerFace);
        myLayout.getChildren().add(timeField);

        //Arc Specifications
        timerFace.setLength(270);
        timerFace.setStartAngle(90);
        timerFace.setRadiusX(100);
        timerFace.setRadiusY(100);
        timerFace.setFill(Color.rgb(29, 69, 40));
        timerFace.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        timerFace.setStrokeType(StrokeType.INSIDE);
        timerFace.setType(ArcType.ROUND);

        //Text Field Specifications
        timeField.setOnAction(myEvent);

        timeField.setOnAction((evt) -> timerFace.setLength(Double.parseDouble(timeField.getCharacters().toString())*6));

While it is functional, I would like to include an if statement in the event handling so that if the user entered number is not within range, it will default to a specified value (360) instead of inducing strange behavior. However, I do not know how to write this, as I only understand the implementation with the lambda function.
I tried to use the Ternary operator as a workaround but the specifications of the lambda function do not allow it. I also looked into the public Java Docs, but I'm struggling to comprehend how to implement the information there.

This may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59260621/limit-textfield-to-a-specific-range-of-number-javafx

You can get other Timer ideas from https://stackoverflow.com/a/50627639/2423906.

The answer posted below and the comments that indicate using a TextFormatter to properly restrict the input are the correct way to approach this. To directly answer the question you asked ("include an if statement in the event handling"), just use the normal syntax for a multiline lambda: timeField.setOnAction( evt -> { double value = Double.parseDouble(timeField.getText()); if (value > 360) { value = 360;} /* etc */ });

Example (using JavaFX/JDK 22), using a TextFormatter.

The text formatter restricts the input to the required values, using a change filter.  The formatter also converts the string value entered to an integer value that can be used in calculations of the arc length.  To update the arc length, it is necessary to press the Enter key in the text field, to commit the text field value, triggering an action handler.
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.converter.IntegerStringConverter;

import java.io.IOException;

public class RestrictedTimeApp extends Application {
    private static final double R = 50;
    private static final double S = R * 2 + 10;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        Arc timeArc = createArc();
        Pane arcPane = createArcPane(timeArc);
        TextField timeField = createTimeField(timeArc);

        VBox layout = new VBox(
                10,
                new Label("Enter Timer Length (1-60min)"),
                timeField,
                arcPane
        );
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    private TextField createTimeField(Arc timeArc) {
        TextField timeField = new TextField();

        TextFormatter<Integer> timeFormatter = new TextFormatter<>(
                new IntegerStringConverter(),
                60,
                this::filter
        );
        timeField.setTextFormatter(
                timeFormatter
        );
        timeField.setOnAction(_ ->
                timeArc.setLength(
                        timeFormatter.getValue() != null
                                ? timeFormatter.getValue() * 6
                                : 0
                )
        );

        return timeField;
    }

    private TextFormatter.Change filter(TextFormatter.Change change) {
        try {
            if (change.getControlNewText().isEmpty()) {
                return change;
            }

            int val = Integer.parseInt(change.getControlNewText());

            return val >= 0 && val <= 60 ? change : null;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static Arc createArc() {
        Arc timeArc = new Arc(R, R, R, R, 0, 360);
        timeArc.setStroke(Color.MEDIUMSLATEBLUE);
        timeArc.setFill(null);
        timeArc.setStrokeWidth(5);
        timeArc.setStrokeLineCap(StrokeLineCap.ROUND);

        return timeArc;
    }

    private static Pane createArcPane(Arc timeArc) {
        Rectangle background = new Rectangle(S, S, Color.TRANSPARENT);

        return new StackPane(new Group(background, timeArc));
    }
}

Setting different arc directions or starting positions and animating the arc for a timer countdown is out of the scope of this answer.
Alternate: use a Spinner
The JavaFX Spinner control, configured with an IntegerSpinnerValueFactory provides similar functionality to what you are requesting here.  Consider using the built-in control, instead of creating a similar implementation.  Providing a Spinner example is out of the scope of this answer.
