# Parsing error - Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"

Tags: java, parsing

Hey when I try to parse string to double I get an error... My code:

```
....
textField.setVisible(true);
double number1 = Double.parseDouble(textField.getText()); ....
```

My error(s):

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
    at zadanieGwiazdka.Ramka$2.actionPerformed(Ramka.java:126)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: removed unnecessary stacktrace

Answer (score 1):

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String

```
textField.getText()
```

returns blank `String`, nothing has entered

You should validate for this scenario before performing click logic

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
```

Suggests you have an empty `String` that is attempted to being converted into some sort of Number (`double`, `int`, etc.). Over here:

double number1 = Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());

Is the issue.  I would recommending only converting after doing some basic checks on this:

```
textField.getText()
```

For example:

```
double number1;
String temp = textField.getText();
if("".equals(temp)){
    number1 = 0.0;//some default value
}
else{
    number1 = Double.parseDouble(textField.getText()); 
}
```

I would recommend doing other checks too for any characters that aren't digits.  I would recommend looking at [this regex solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5011958/2498729)